# Rails Semantics, Model.find() in a controller (yes or no?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just had a small conversation with a friend, and he had mentioned that some people don't like `Model.find(params[:id])` in the controller.

He said the alternative is to have an interface. That you're not sending messages to an object with the other method.

Could someone explain this and give an example?

Thanks!

Comment: I think [this post: 'Making Rails Models Thin'](http://solnic.eu/2011/08/01/making-activerecord-models-thin.html) explains the concept fairly well.

Comment: Thank you, it did splendidly! Offer it as an answer and I'll pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post: ['Making Rails Models Thin'](http://solnic.eu/2011/08/01/making-activerecord-models-thin.html) explains the concept fairly well.